# Exported .bas module has an attribute what does it mean?

Tags: excel, vba

```
`Attribute  <mySubName>.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "W\n14"`
```

I did not change the default name of module1.bas when exported out.

Comment: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/24882-regd-vb-procdata-vb-invoke-func/

Comment: Thanks, Shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+W  this is the case!